# How to filter only fields that are objects Mongodb

Tags: mongodb, meteor, aggregation-framework

This is my sample Document.

```
{
   "_id": "ABHWRvStvb3fLqTA2",
   "aa": "aaaa",
   "bb": "bbbb",
   "cc": {
      "c": 545,
      "cc": 43,
      "ccc": 56
   },
   "dd": {
      "d": 45,
      "dd": 564,
      "ddd": 454
   }
}
```

How do i get the fields that of type Object.I checked out the [doc](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/bson-types/).Object is type 3.How do I query the document for only fields that are objects.

The result should be something like this.

```
{
   "cc": {
      "c": 545,
      "cc": 43,
      "ccc": 56
   },
   "dd": {
      "d": 45,
      "dd": 564,
      "ddd": 454
   }
}
```

Is their anyway to do this without using Map Reduce.I am using this in my meteor application so i also want to keep the query reactive.

Thanks!!

Comment: Do you know which fields are objects and wich aren't before running your query?

Comment: They will be dynamically added.So at the time of querying i dunno how many fields are their and how many of them are objects.

Comment: Do you want to use this filter query inside a publish or just on client code?

Comment: Inside a publish.